# What is the best suitable .NET type to save GEO coordinates?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, geolocation, coordinate-systems

Please, suggest me how I can parse and handle coordinates that originally come as text:

```
N5004.8 E01300.0
```

As far I know, the first thing is replace North/South and East/West to positive and negative values, but which are negative?. South and West?

The second thing, confirm my assumption that it can be written as double in .NET as

```
50.048d and 1.300d
```

Is't correct assumption?

And the last thing is how I can use System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography to save these coordinates to SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: In SQL server you have geography data type for storing GEO coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that shows how to use spatial types with EF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) article can also be helpful. As for parsing EF is using so called [Well Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) (WKT) and your format does not look like it so you will most likely will have to understand what format your data is using and translate it accordingly.